# How can i add response header to a pdf in CQ5

Tags: pdf, aem, sling, response-headers

I am trying add canonical tags to PDF and for that i have to update response header when PDF is loaded. I was able to add header for cq:page very easily:

```
@SlingServlet(
   resourceTypes = "cq:Page",
   extensions = "html",
   methods = "GET")

@Properties({
@Property(name = "service.description", value = "Servlet to handle all incoming widget modification")
})
    public class canocalizePDF extends SlingAllMethodsServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(SlingHttpServletRequest request,   SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.addHeader(“canonical", “test");
    }
    @Override
    protected void doPost(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }
}
```

But when i try to same for PDF, it is not working. I have tried dam:Asset, dam:AssetContent as resourceTypes, but nothing seems to be working.

Any help would be great.

Thanks,
Vishal

Comment: Are these PDFs part of the static DAM assets ?

Comment: Yes, something like /content/dam/pdf/en/citrix-workspace-suite-brochure.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The servlet that you've written is not handling your asset requests. If you want to handle this in AEM, you will need to override the OOTB AEM's `AssetDownloadServlet` with your own servlet implementation. You can then add the canonical link header in your servlet response.
How to override this is explained in detail in [this blog post](http://www.computepatterns.com/153/overriding-out-of-the-box-servlet-in-aem-sling/). They've also included a link to sample code for this customization.

However, if you have a webserver (e.g. Apache) in your setup, you should really handle this there. This is shown in this [Moz blog post](https://moz.com/blog/htaccess-file-snippets-for-seos). Moz is the pinnacle of SEO best practices. I will recommend that.

Comment: Thanks Abhishek, if i handle this via my conf file in Apache then i will have to make an entry for each pdf file. I am making an entry in JCR for the canonical link and then i would read that link and then add that to response header. Let me try that link that you suggested.

Comment: I used the code in the link you suggested but it doesn't even do anything when i load a pdf. Is it possible for you to try this at your end. Will really appreciate.